# Yii File Translation Automatic On $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']

Tags: translation, yii

I want to do yii file translation and a set in my `protected/views/layouts/main.php`:

```
<?php
  if(preg_match('/de/', $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']))
    Yii::app()->language='de';
?>
```

In `protected/config/main.php` I set `'sourceLanguage'=>'en_us'`, `'language' => 'en'`

I have two language folders `views/site/de` and `views/site/en`.

The files from the de directory are never loaded when the  `Yii::app()->language='de';` is called in the `layout/main` view. But, when I set `'language' => 'de'`, in the config file it is loaded.

Is there a way to fix it, such that the language folders are used depending on the users browser language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But why you set `Yii::app()->language` into the view? I think, that problem may be in it - because at this moment all translated messages are loaded. So, try to do it in controller (or in filter).